# Multiple cases and order_by at the same query in sql sentence?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a quite complex search for SQL and after couple of attempts trying to use multiple cases for the query, I wonder if it is posible to do all in one query or if I need to split the task.

Table `invoices` includes, among others, `customer_id, customer_version, startDate (DateTime) and status.`

This is the goal:

```
From invoices,
when customer_id='123' and customer_version="321" select invoice according to status.

if there are one or more past_due invoices, pick the older one.

if there is no past_due invoice, pick the first open invoice,

if there is no open invoice, pick the last paid invoice,

if there is no paid invoice, pick the future invoice,

if there is no future invoice, pick the last draft,

if there is no draft, then retrieve a null value for all invoice.
```

Is it possible to query with cases, using different startDate orders (ASC, DESC) checking for nulls and picking by status, at the same `SELECT sql phrase`? Can some one give an example?

Answer (score 1):

First, create examples for all these cases, and order them correctly by their intended priority:

```
status    date
--------------
past_due   d1
past_due   d2
open       d1
open       d2
paid       d2
paid       d1
future     ?
draft      d2
draft      d1
```

Then, assign numbers so that `ORDER BY status2, date2` would work correctly.
(If we assume that dates are numbers, `-d2` is smaller than `-d1`, i.e., negating them reverses the sort direction.)

```
status    date  status2  date2
------------------------------
past_due   d1      1      d1
past_due   d2      1      d2
open       d1      2      d1
open       d2      2      d2
paid       d2      3     -d2
paid       d1      3     -d1
future     ?       4      ?
draft      d2      5     -d2
draft      d1      5     -d1
```

Then use [CASE expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case) to map the status values to these numbers, and to modify the dates accordingly.
([julianday()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) returns a number if the date values are in a supported format; the actual meaning of Julian days does not matter as long as they compare correctly to each other.)

```
SELECT customer_id,
       customer_version,
       startDate,
       status
FROM invoices
WHERE customer_id = 123
  AND customer_version = '321'
ORDER BY CASE status
           WHEN 'past_due' THEN 1
           WHEN 'open'     THEN 2
           WHEN 'paid'     THEN 3
           WHEN 'future'   THEN 4
           WHEN 'draft'    THEN 5
         END,
         CASE
           WHEN status IN ('past_due', 'open', 'future')
           THEN  julianday(startDate)  -- earliest date first
           ELSE -julianday(startDate)  -- latest date first
         END
LIMIT 1
```

The `LIMIT 1` then returns only the first of these sorted rows (if any has been found).